# The Laplacian in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, laplacian

$\DeclareMathOperator\Dom{Dom}$I'm trying to prove that $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus[0,\infty)$, then $G_{z}(H_{0})f \in \Dom(H_{0})$ and
$$
(H_{0} -z)G_{z}(H_{0})f = f
$$

The notations are below.

We know that
$$
-\triangle f = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[|\xi|^{2}\mathcal{F}(f)], \ \ \forall f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})
$$
Therefore, it is natural to introduce the operator $(-\triangle)$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, denoted by $H_{0}$, through the formulas,
\begin{eqnarray}
\Dom(H_{0}) = H^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) = \lbrace f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},dx);|\xi|^{2}\mathcal{F}(f) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},d\xi)\rbrace
\end{eqnarray}
and
$$
H_{0}f = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[M_{0}\mathcal{F}(f)], \ \ f \in \Dom(H_{0}),
$$
where $M_{0}$ is the maximal operator of multiplication by $|\xi|^{2}$ on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},d\xi)$, this is,
$$
\Dom(M_{0}) = \lbrace g \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},d\xi); |\xi|^{2}g \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},d\xi)\rbrace
$$
and
$$
(M_{0}g)(\xi) = |\xi|^{2}g(\xi), \ \ g \in \Dom(M_{0}), \ \ \xi - \text{q.t.p}.
$$
Now define $G : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ a measurable function. Define the operator $G(H_{0})$ through the formulas
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\Dom(G(H_{0})) & = & \lbrace f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},dx); G(|\xi|^{2})\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},d\xi)\rbrace \\ 
~ \\
G(H_{0})f& = & \mathcal{F}^{-1}[G(M_{0})\mathcal{F}(f)], \ \ f \in \Dom(G(H_{0}))
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray*}
where $G(M_{0})$ is the maximal operator of multiplication by $G(|\xi|^{2})$ em $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},d\xi)$, this is,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\Dom(G(M_{0})) & = & \lbrace \phi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},dx); G(|\xi|^{2})\phi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n},d\xi)\rbrace \\ 
~ \\
(G(M_{0})\phi)(\xi)& = & G(|\xi|^{2})\phi(\xi), \ \ \phi \in \Dom(G(H_{0}))
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray*}

The resolving operator is obtained from
$$
G_{z}(|\xi|^{2}) = (|\xi|^{2}-z)^{-1}, \ \ \xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \ \ z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty).
$$

Comment: You can use Fourier transform and definitions to show both $G_z(H_0)f\in D(H_0)$ and the identity. Did you have a try?

Comment: @Feng I tried but I didn't succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $z\in\mathbb C\setminus[0,\infty)$, then $\text{dist }(z, [0,\infty))=:\delta>0$.
Given $f\in L^2$, then $\hat f\in L^2$. ($\hat f$ means the Fourier tansform of $f$, i.e. $\hat f=\mathcal{F}f$)

- $|G_z(|\xi^2|)|=\left|\frac1{|\xi|^2-z}\right|\leq\frac1\delta$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb R^n$, so $G_z(|\xi|^2)\hat f(\xi)\in L^2$, and thus $f\in \text{Dom}(G_z(H_0))$ and $(G_z(H_0)f)^{\hat\ }(\xi)=G_z(|\xi|^2)\hat f(\xi)$.
- Now we prove that $G_z(H_0)f\in\text{Dom}(H_0)$. Indeed, since $G_z(|\xi|^2)\hat f(\xi)\in L^2$ we have $G_z(H_0)f\in L^2$; also we have
  $$ |\xi|^2(G_z(H_0)f)^{\hat\ }(\xi)=\frac{|\xi|^2}{|\xi|^2-z}\hat f(\xi)=\left(1+\frac{z}{|\xi|^2-z}\right)\hat f(\xi),$$
  and $\sup_{\xi\in\mathbb R^n}\left|1+\frac{z}{|\xi|^2-z}\right|\leq 1+\frac{|z|}\delta<\infty$, and so $|\xi|^2(G_z(H_0)f)^{\hat\ }(\xi)\in L^2$. This checks that $G_z(H_0)f\in\text{Dom}(H_0)$.
- Finally, by definition,
  $$\mathcal{F}\Big((H_0-z)G_z(H_0)f\Big)(\xi)=(|\xi|^2-z)\mathcal{F}(G_z(H_0)f)(\xi)=(|\xi|^2-z)G_z(|\xi|^2)\hat f(\xi)=\hat f(\xi),\ \forall\xi\in\mathbb R^n.$$
  Therefore, $(H_0-z)G_z(H_0)f=f$.